# How can I write this function on mouse hover a div?

Tags: javascript

How can I write this function so that when the mouse is resting over the div .resting it will trigger the call. Here is the code:

```
$(document).bind('mousemove', function() {
     resetActive()
});
```

I want it to call the resetActive when the mouse is resting over a desired div .resting. How can I write the code?

Comment: $("div.resting").mouseover(function() {} ) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.resting').mouseenter(resetActive);
```

Or, to be clean and better practice,

```
$('.resting').on('mouseenter', resetActive);

// and later
$('.resting').off('mouseenter', resetActive);
```

And to get the event:

```
var resetActive = function(e) {
  // do something...
}
```

Comment: Why `bind()`/`unbind()` instead of `on()`/`off ()`?

Comment: Please note that .on/.off is encouraged by the jQuery team, instead of .bind/.unbind or .eventname

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".resting").mouseover(function() {
    resetActive();
});
```

Comment: An using an ID is not necessary since the OP provides a class that they're using.